# TX light not flashing, screen.print works sometimes.. UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I've got 2 Analog accelerometers and a Gyro/Acc/Mag connected to my arduino and it's been working and reading fine until a few hours ago. 
I've got the arduino sending data over the serial connection and Unity reading the values and interpreting.

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LSM303.h>
#include <L3G.h>

LSM303 compass;
L3G gyro;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  compass.init();
  compass.enableDefault();
  gyro.init();
  gyro.enableDefault();
}

void loop() {

  /* Accelerometers: */

  int sensorValueA = analogRead(A0);
  int sensorValueB = analogRead(A1);
  //Serial.flush();
  Serial.print(sensorValueA);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(sensorValueB);
  delay(10);

  /* Accelerometer + Magnometer: */

  compass.read();
  //Serial.flush();
  Serial.print(compass.a.x);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(compass.a.y);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(compass.a.z);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(compass.m.x);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(compass.m.y);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(compass.m.z);
  delay(10);

  /* Gyro: */

  gyro.read();
  //Serial.flush();
  Serial.print((int)gyro.g.x);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print((int)gyro.g.y);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println((int)gyro.g.z);
  delay(10);

}
```

If I have it unplugged for several minutes then replug it, the print will work for a min or two then just stop completely. I've checked wires several times and it hasn't moved since it was working this morning.

As I said, which I think is probably of importance, the TX light is off when not printing.

[image]
*Acc1:* GND - GND | VCC - 3.3v | Y - A2

*Acc2:* GND - GND | VCC - 3.3v | Y - A3

*Gyro:* VIN - 5v | GND - GND | SAO - A4 | SCL - A5

Thanks

Comment: My guess is your I2C communications are locking up.  We'd need to see your setup though (schematic, pictures, etc) to be able to help further though.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem with only 1 sensor attached?
If you can, that makes debugging much simpler.

Comment: Include a counter variable that increments once per pass of loop(). Dump the value before you start all the printing commands, then see if the lockup is happening after a similar running time. I've had this happen before with a straightforward "breathing LED" sketch: my cheap Chinese Uno was fine but my genuine version would hang after 90-120 seconds. Never got to the bottom of it!